# Prove that we can construct a line segment with the length $\sqrt{n}$.

Tags: geometry, induction

**Question**

If a line segment with the length $1$ is given then prove that we can construct a line segment with the length $\sqrt{n}$ for any $n \in \Bbb N$.

**My approach:**

I am looking for a solution using induction. For the base case it is obvious and like always the problem is the case $n+1$. I'm trying to use

$$n=(\sqrt{n+1}-1)(\sqrt{n+1}+1)$$

but I can't go further.

Any idea?

Comment: There's a typical way to construct $\sqrt{n}$. It's technically possible to do it with the rationals, too. I assume you don't want this?

Comment: @Kaynex: Right! I don't! Thanks anyway!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2931624/589

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** If you have line segments of length $1$ and $\sqrt n$, then constructing a certain right triangle will give you something of length $\sqrt{1+n}$.

---

The classical solution -- without induction! -- is to construct $\sqrt n$ as the [mean proportional](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Construction_of_Mean_Proportional) between line segments of length $1$ and $n$.

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks!

Comment: We are not given length $n$, how can we use it in the second method?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: Supposedly you know the _number_ $n$, so just put that many unit line segments after one another (e.g. extend the unit line segment you have indefintely and use the compass $n$ times to put equidistant marks on it).

Answer (score 3):

You are perhaps looking for something like the [Spiral of Theodorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus), an incremental set of right triangles with the root of every integer as the hypotenuses.

Picture from Wikipedia:

[image]