# Constructing segments of length $\sqrt{13}$ and $\sqrt{22}$, given a segment of length $1$

Tags: geometry, radicals, irrational-numbers

> Given a line segment of $1$ unit in length construct a line segment that is
>
> - $\sqrt{13}$ in length
> - $\sqrt{22}$ in length

Is it best to use the root spiral of theodorus or is there a more efficient method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt {13}$ is the hypotenuse of the right triangle with legs $2,3$.  Now, $22$ isn't the sum of two squares so that's a bit harder, but [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705/compass-and-straightedge-construction-of-the-square-root-of-a-given-line) should help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to construct a line segment with length $\sqrt{13}$, I would construct it as the hypotenuse of a right triangle such that the length of the other two sides are $2$ and $3$. After that, I would construct another right triangle whose catheti have lengths $\sqrt{13}$ and $3$. The length of its hypotenuse will then be equal to $\sqrt{22}$.

Answer (score 5):

It is easy to construct $\sqrt a$ for each $a$ that is constructible:
[image]

(picture from [commons.wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Square_root_construction.svg))